# Style Button in Header of JQuery Mobile App

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, markup, jquery-mobile-button

I have a JQuery Mobile app. I want to style the buttons that are used in the "header".  Currently, I have the following:

```
.my-btn-hdr { text-transform:uppercase; background-color:blue; color:white; min-height:33px; width:93px; }
...

<div id="myPage" data-role="page" data-dom-cache="false">
  <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <a href="#" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="notext" data-direction="reverse" class="ui-btn-left jqm-back">Back</a>
    <h1>MyApp</h1>
    <a id="saveButton" href="#" class="ui-btn-right my-btn-hdr">Save</a>
  </div>

  <div data-role="content">        
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

i've noticed when the page gets rendered, the ui-btn, ui-btn-up-a, ui-shadow, and ui-button-corner-all css classes are getting added. I also noticed that the data-corners="true", data-shadow="true", and data-iconshadow="true" attributes are getting added.

How do I customize the style of a button in the header of a jquery mobile app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you need to know can be found in official documentation: http://api.jquerymobile.com/button/

For example if you want to change button theme you would use this function:

```
$( "a" ).buttonMarkup({ theme: "c" });
```

Here's a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/eqLVV/

If something is not mentioned in the documentation then you will need to change it through css, here's a button structure after jQM rendered it:

```
<a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-up-c">
    <span class="ui-btn-inner">
        <span class="ui-btn-text">Anchor</span>
    </span>
</a>
```

One last thing, if you need to manually change css, always add !important at the end of css line in case something is not working.

For example, this can be used to change button text color:

```
#btn1 .ui-btn-inner .ui-btn-text {
    color: red;
}
```

and here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/k5jty/

Answer (score 0):

You can give your button a custom class and then overwrite any styles that you want to change or remove.

```
<a data-role="button" class="my-button">
```

CSS:

```
.my-button {
    background-image: url('images/my-button.png') !important;
}
```